# How can I access data of Laminas\Stdlib\Parameters Object in in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, admin, file-upload

I want to access Laminas\Stdlib\Parameters Object data in that I
can access video_url data in magento2. How can I access that object data ?

```
$product = $this->getRequest()->getFiles();
print_r($product);
```

Using that I got this below object but I want to access video_url data.

```
Laminas\Stdlib\Parameters Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [product] => Array
                (
                    [video_url] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4
                            [type] => video/mp4
                            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpb5ZS51
                            [error] => 0
                            [size] => 1570024
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this belove code i got the solution

```
 $json  = json_encode($product);
 $array = json_decode($json, true);
 print_r($array['product']['video_url']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
$productData = $product->get('product');
```

Where $productData content will be **video_url** index data.

Comment: that not working for me

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can read contents of the file from `getRequest()->getFiles();`

```
$file = $this->getRequest()->getFiles()->get('file');
$data = file_get_contents($file['tmp_name']);
$this->logger->info($data);
```